# How to get database version through Hibernate?

Tags: sql, database, hibernate

Is there a way to get some information of the underlying database version through the Hibernate 3.2 API? I failed to find relevant bits both here and the javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the version of your database engine is implementation specific. This means that there's no shared method for getting the version and so Hibernate cannot really provide an API since it is not bound to any particular RDBMS. For example, here are some different ways you get the version with SELECT statements from some well-known RDBMSs:

- **Oracle**: SELECT * FROM v$version;
- **SQL Server**: SELECT @@version
- **MySQL**: SELECT VERSION()
- ...

You could create a view that reports the version and then add that to your ORM which would then be accessible as any other Hibernate object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing such detailed explanation. Will try the method you proposed. Should be easy since I only need to support Oracle and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void testConnection() {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.doWork(connection -> {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");
            resultSet.next();
            System.out.println("DB test: " + resultSet.getString(1));
        });
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach than the accepted answer is to use the java.sql.DatabaseMetaData class:

```java
    try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        session.doWork(connection -> {
            DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("Product version: " + metaData.getDatabaseProductVersion());
            System.out.println("Major version: " + metaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion());
            System.out.println("Minor version: " + metaData.getDatabaseMinorVersion());
         });
     }
```

For my MySQL 5.5 instance, this outputs:

```
Product version: 5.5.62-log
Major version: 5
Minor version: 5
```

The Product version is identical to the value returned by SELECT VERSION();

Answer (score 0):

Possible with some unwraps:

```
Session hibSession = ... // session is taken from wherever is possible
String dbVersion = hibSession.unwrap(SharedSessionContractImplementor.class)
    .getJdbcCoordinator()
    .getLogicalConnection()
    .getPhysicalConnection()
    .getMetadata()
    .getDatabaseProductVersion();
```

There are also separate methods for major/minor versions available, as well as JDBC protocol version, DB vendor name etc.