# Is there any way to get RDBMS name and version using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I want to get information about sql server from application like :"MySql 5.6.16".

Comment: Don't know about JPA, but JDBC has `DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductVersion()` and `getDatabaseProductName()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getDatabaseProductName%28%29

Comment: See [Is there any way to get RDBMS name and version using JPA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540901/how-to-get-database-version-through-hibernate).